# Issue on Storing Facebook Web Login JavaScript SDK to Database

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I am getting these errors when trying to use Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK to store the user data into the database.

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$gender in /home/domain/public_html/loguser/facebook.php on line 30
Undefined property: stdClass::$locale in /home/domain/public_html/loguser/facebook.php on line 31
Undefined property: stdClass::$link in /home/domain/public_html/loguser/facebook.php on line 33
```

Apparently on Browser I am getting `Gender  :   undefined` message for one test login so in case like this thata a user may not specified his/her `Gender`, `Locale` or `link` how can I prevent this error on PHP side?

```
function verify_user() {
  FB.api('/me', {locale: 'en_US', fields: 'id, name, first_name, last_name,email, link, gender,locale, picture'},
  function (response) {
      $.ajax({
      url: "facebook.php",
      data: {userinfo : JSON.stringify(response)},
      type: "POST",
      success: function(resp) {
        //Your cutom code after successful login 
      }
    });
  });  
}
```

and on `facebook.php` I have

```
$qry_body = "  `oauth_provider` = 'facebook',
          `oauth_id`     = '".$userInfo->id."',
          `name`           = '".$userInfo->name."',
          `first_name`     = '".$userInfo->first_name."', 
          `last_name`      = '".$userInfo->last_name."', 
          `email`          = '".$userInfo->email."', 
          `gender`         = '".$userInfo->gender."', 
          `locale`         = '".$userInfo->locale."', 
          `picture`        = '".$userInfo->picture->data->url."', 
          `link`           = '".$userInfo->link."', 
          `modified`       = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' ";
```

Comment: Check what `response` actually contains. Just because you request a number of fields in your API call, does not necessarily mean that the response will also contain an entry for each one of those.

Comment: Thanks misorude, you are right! I am not seeing any of `gender` `link` or `locale` returned on the respond!  But I am requesting them through `FB.api('/me', {locale: 'en_US', fields: 'id, name, first_name, last_name,email, link, gender,locale, picture'}` any idea why I am not getting them back?

Comment: `gender` and `link` both require their own permission these days, most likely you did not ask the user to grant those. (But even with permission, you will not get a `gender` value for every user.) And the `locale` field has been removed IIRC.